# c# How to assign an alphanumeric primary key to a return variable

Tags: c#

I'm a noob with Object Oriented Programming and C# in particular.  I'm attending night school to learn C#, but my knowledge level is at the monkey-see-monkey-do level.  I have some code here and some elementary questions:

---

```
public static String InsertProduct(SqlConnection cnSQL, String strProductDesc, String strProductHS, String strManufacturer)
    {
        SqlCommand cmdSQL;
        Int32 intRetCode = 0;
        String strProductKey;


        if (cnSQL != null)
        {
            cmdSQL = new SqlCommand();
            cmdSQL.Connection = cnSQL;
            cmdSQL.CommandText = "uspInsertProduct";
            cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductDesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@ProductDesc"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@ProductDesc"].Value = strProductDesc;

            ********************************
             Code removed for brevity
            *********************************

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@ProductID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            try
            {
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                intRetCode = -1;
            }
           ************Offending Code Start
           strProductKey = cmdSQL.Parameters["@ProductID"].ToString;
           ************Offend Code End
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Clear();
            cmdSQL.Dispose();
      }
            return strProductKey; 

    }
```

What is returned when I have this statement "cmdSQL.Parameters["@ProductID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;"?  A record number or the actual key?

Assuming the answer is the actual key, how do I construct the variable assignment so I can return it to the calling routine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question:

The actual return value is determined by the stored procedure `uspInsertProduct`. You'd have to look into SQL to see the definition of that stored procedure to find your answer.

For the second part:

You have to get the value of the output parameter after you call the stored procedure.

```
try
{
    cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
    strProductKey = cmdSQL.Parameters["@ProductID"].Value;
}

...

return strProductKey;
```